# check if method exists in ReactJS stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

If find myself constantly firing methods of the props:

```
 const Menu = (props) => <div style={styles.container}
                    onClick={(ev) => props.menuClick(ev, props.item)}>...</div>
```

But those methods are sometimes optional. How can I fire the method only if it's exists?

This seem unreadable:

```
 const Menu = (props) => <div style={styles.container}
    onClick={(ev) => props.menuClick ? props.menuClick(props.item_id, ev) : ()=>{} }>
```

Perhaps there is somekind of a propType meets default value thing can turn all incoming methods which are not populated to void anonymous functions?

**UPDATE:**

For methods without parameters, as mentioned in the comment section, this is valid even if not given:

```
const Menu = (props) => <div style={styles.container}
                    onClick={props.menuClick}>...</div>
```

as ReactJS excepts onClick={null}

Comment: you can just do `props.menuClick || () => {}` instead of ?:

Comment: I'm pretty sure `onClick={null}` is valid in React and won't throw errors when it's clicked?

Comment: Also third example if the params are the same for the function you call you don't need to wrap it, they will be passed just right.

Comment: @T4rk1n nice, it does simplify things when there are no params. You're right about the third example - I modified it now.

Comment: @Guy but now item_id is undefined.

Comment: @AndyRay I've checked just now - you're right. onClick={null} is safe. onClick={(e) => {this.props.click(e, item)} is not. Raises a "is not a function" error.

Comment: @T4rk1n yes :-) fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can define your function by ES6 class with default props that contains your default empty function:

```
class Menu extends Component {
 static defaultProps = {
  onClick: () => {}
 }

 render() {
  return(<div style={styles.container} onClick={this.props.onClick}></div>);
 }
}
```